# C++ SFML screen boundary collision

Tags: c++, sfml

I have this snippet of my whole code here:

```
        if (player.playerSprite.getPosition().x <= 0) //Left
                player.playerSprite.setPosition(0.f, player.playerSprite.getPosition().y);

        if (player.playerSprite.getPosition().x >= window.getSize().x - player.playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().width) //Right
            player.playerSprite.setPosition(window.getSize().x - player.playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().width, player.playerSprite.getPosition().y);

        if (player.playerSprite.getPosition().y <= 0) //Top
    player.playerSprite.setPosition(player.playerSprite.getPosition().x, 0.f);

        if (player.playerSprite.getPosition().y >= window.getSize().y - player.playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().height) //Bottom
    player.playerSprite.setPosition(player.playerSprite.getPosition().x, window.getSize().y - player.playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().height);
```

The left and top are working fine (the sprite collides into them but not pass through) but the sprite won't even come near the right and the bottom sides. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `getLocalBounds` instead of `getGlobalBounds`?

Comment: @Nelfeal It shouldn't matter if the bound rectangle is locally or globally placed, width and height should be the same if the sprite wasn't **transformed**. If the sprite was transformed (moved, rotated or scaled), then `getGlobalBounds()` should be used.

Comment: That bound check works fine for me (VS2013), may be something related with your sprite movement? Are you checking values for `width` and `height`? If they are zero, your sprite will go out of the window.